# How does threading (asynchronous queues) work in Swift?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

ok I am updating this question but left the old one there. 
So I have an array that stores the data for different views in a uipageviewcontroller. I need to grab image data in the background. I don't understand how to code this though within an asynchronous task.
Heres the code for the task:

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue()

                queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
                    // do something in the background
                    println("background")
                    self.cards[newIndex].loadImag()
                    var cardimages = self.cards[newIndex].images
                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() {
                        // when done, update your UI and/or model on the main queue
                        println("update ui")
                        self.cards[newIndex].images = cardimages
                    }
                }
```

this is what the .loadImag() function looks like:

```
    func loadImag(){
        println("images= \(self.images)")

        if self.

location_id != nil && (self.images == nil) {
        println("before api call loc_id= \(self.location_id)")
    ApiWrapper.getPictures(self.location_id!, completionHandler: self.imagesCallback)
    }
    }
}
```

and this is self.imagesCallback code:

```
private func imagesCallback(cardImagesArray: [CardImage]){
    println("images callback id= \(self.location_id)")
    self.images = cardImagesArray
}
```

problem is I am not sure how to put this code inside of the operation cue since the function must have a callback. How can I get the operation queue working so that it updates the self.card array in the uipageviewcontroller?

OLD QUESTION_________________:
So I have this line of code I need to run concurrently in a different thread than the main thread. When I add it to the main queue like so:

```
var queue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
dispatch_async(queue, {
    self.cards[newIndex].loadImage()
})
```

doing this it works fine but doesn't seem to run concurrently. When I change the queue to concurrent like this:

```
dispatch_async(DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT, {
    self.cards[newIndex].loadImage()
})
```

The app crashes saying "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". What am I doing wrong here? Also when I run the self.cards[newIndex].loadImage() function in a different concurrent thread will this update the values in the main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shouldn't use GCD unless you want to explicitly use functionality which is only available on GCD. For your case it is more beneficial (and cleaner in code) to use NSOperationQueue. NSOperationQueue uses GCD in the background and is more secure (less ways to mess up)

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue()

queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
    // do something in the background

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() {
        // when done, update your UI and/or model on the main queue
    }
}
```

You can also read through the Apple [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1)
The guide is using examples with Objective-C but API is basically the same for Swift.

It also might look strange but with the `addOperationWithBlock()` I used something called "trailing closure" you can read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) about it

Comment: this seems to be working but Im not sure how to have the api call in a block like that since it must use a callback. I updated the question with more code that I have

Comment: accepted your answer... finally got this working thanks!

Comment: that is actually a block. In Swift it is called "trailing closure" have a look here
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html
I also updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dispatch_get_global_queue` . Try something like:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue, {self.cards[newIndex].loadImage()})
```

`dispatch_get_main_queue()`, as you were trying, runs on the UI/main thread, which is why you saw the behavior you did.

To answer the second part of your question, If `loadImage()` is modifying the UI, you don't want to do that from a background thread. It *must* be done from the main/UI thread. A typical idiom would be, from the main thread do:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue, {
    <code to load/prepare images>
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        <code to update UI elements>   
    })
})
```

Comment: loadImage() is modifying the ui in the sense it grabs data (images) of a place before that view is loaded. Even with the dispatch_get_global_queue I am still having the problem then when I bring up a new view the api request to the backend doesn't run until all of the async tasks are done. How can I get it so that when  new view comes up that view and its api calls go ahead of the loadImage() calls?

Comment: You may need to post additional code to demonstrate your problem. Also, see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the whole code so we can see what are you doing? 
Below is very basic code snippet. This is basically how concurrency works in Swift.

```
let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value)
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0), { () -> Void in

// Put your code here to work in the background

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            // Put your code here when the process is done and hand over to the main thread.
            // Ex. self.cards[newIndex].loadImage()
        })
    })
```